# How to get get last character on getchar()!=EOF

Tags: c

Is there any way to get the last element before EOF while using `getchar()`?

E.g I have a text saying
"Hey there
 people"

What would be the condition to check the last char in that text (in our example e). My thoughts are the following but i am not sure what the if condition should be.

```
//pseydocode

int c;
while(c=getchar() != EOF)
    if(c==EOF-1) //assuming EOF is the end EOF -1 would be the last  character.
        if(c==O) print O;
        else if(c==P) print P;
        else if (c==e) print e;
```

I want to check the very last character and if it's a specific letter to print it.

Thank you.

Comment: `EOF` is a special value that means "End Of File". `EOF-1` makes no sense. It's quite unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Yea i know i struggle on finding what would that if condition should be to get the last character.

Comment: Still unclear what you want. The last character is the one returned by `getchar` before `EOF`. You need to handle this.

Comment: `while(c=getchar() != EOF)` ==> `while((c=getchar()) != EOF)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no indication that the character just returned from `getchar` is the last available character. To print the last character before `EOF`, you must remember the return from `getchar`. When `EOF` is returned, then print the previously remembered character.

For example, this code prints the last character of a stream:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, previous = EOF;

    while (1)
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        previous = c;
    }

    if (previous == EOF)
        printf("There were no characters in the stream.\n");
    else
        printf("The last character was %c.\n", previous);
}
```

When you try the above, you are likely to find the last character is a new-line character, `'\n'`.

In general, it would be impossible for a C implementation to know the character just returned is the last character. Input might be coming from a terminal, for example, and the user has just typed a character, which `getchar()` returns. At this point, we do not know what the user will do next—they might type another character, or they might type and end-of-file indication (as by pressing control-D twice, in a Unix system). So, having just gotten a character, we do not know whether what is coming next is another character or is `EOF`.

Comment: @PeterGrifison You'll want to save the previously read character in another variable, and use that if `getchar()` returns `EOF` to do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Gotcha .Thanks guys. Was more simple that i though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the code to remember the last character(if any at all) before EOF.

```
int c;
int lc = EOF;
while((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
   lc = c;
}

//here lc will hold the last character read before EOF,
//or it will also be EOF if no characters got read at all.
```

Note that your original condition was `while(c=getchar() != EOF)`, which is incorrect - it is evaluated as `while(c=(getchar() != EOF))`, you have to write `while((c=getchar()) != EOF`

Comment: `while(c=getchar() != EOF)` ==> `while((c=getchar()) != EOF)`

Answer (score 1):

```
char c; 
int tmp = 0; 
while(tmp != EOF) 
{ 
  c = (char)tmp; 
  tmp=getchar(); 
}
```

`c` becomes `0` (null terminator) in case of an empty input, otherwise it is the last character before `EOF`.